# Load cfg file in kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, firmware, touch-screen

I have a touch panel (goodix) and I need to send the device configuration to the firmware. I have a *.cfg file but  I neither know nor find how to load this file.

Do you know what is the way to load this file?

Answer (score 1):

You do not read configuration files from the kernel. 
Technically this is possible but there aren‘t any drivers who do read config files. See this article by Greg KH, http://m.linuxjournal.com/article/8110.

You can read firmware files, which have a predefined fixed format, from the kernel. This can be done by calling 
request_firmware(). See: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/firmware_class.c#L1221 and

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/firmware_class/